# Covariant Derivative of New Timelike coordinate

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, differentiation, vector-fields

In another [forum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/718108/), someone was explaining to me how to define a new time coordinate in a metric tensor to diagonalize it. They said that if I want  spacelike hypersurfaces, the covariant derivative of $\tau$ should be timelike. Does $\tau$ count as a vector? If not, how would I take the covariant derivative?

Comment: $\tau$ is a coordinate, meaning it is a function. It’s covariant derivative is by definition simply its exterior derivative/differential $d\tau$. CHecking whether this is timeline/space like amounts to looking at the sign of the coefficient of $d\tau^2$ in the metric.

Comment: Would the covariant derivative with raised indice also just be the regular derivative in this case?

Comment: $\nabla^af=g^{ab}\nabla_bf=g^{ab}(df)_b=g^{ab}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^b}$ if that’s what you want to know. This is what we’d call the ($a^{th}$ component of) gradient vector field of $f$, i.e $\text{grad}_g(f)$.

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. Thank you.